# VBA Words table; How do I only reference the first column?

Tags: vba, ms-word

Sorry everyone I'm still very new to VBA. I'm trying to fill text only in the first column but it goes over to the next column, how do I only reference the first column so that it prints going down the column, also how do I break the loop?

thanks

```
       For Each c In ThisDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells

           c.Range.Text = ("Description" & x)
        x = x + 1
    Next c

   End With

End With
```

Comment: You can use `ThisDocument.Tables(1).Columns(1).Cells`.

Comment: @ Domenic Perfect thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use an indexed loop instead of a `For Each` loop and then address the cell like this

```
.Cell(lRow, lCol).Range.Text

ThisDocument.Tables(1).Range.Cells(1, 2).Range.Text
```

Comment: I'm for asking you to hold my hand, but how would it look in its entirety